# python multiprocessing - access the process name inside the function called with Process.start(target=func)

Tags: python, inheritance, multiprocessing

I am playing around with python multiprocessing module and wanted to be able to display the name of the currently executing process.

If I create a custom MyProcess class inheriting from multiprocessing.Process I can print the process's name in the following way

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyProcess(Process):
   def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)

   def run(self):
        #do something nasty and print the name
        print self.name

p = MyProcess()
p.start()
```

However if I am creating processes using the constructor of Process class

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def somefunc():
    print Process.name                 #1

p = Process(target=somefunc)
p.start()
print p.name                           #2
```

#2 works but #1 doesn't. Is there a way I could print the name of the currently executing process inside `somefunc`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`current_process`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.current_process) function:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def somefunc():
    print current_process().name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=somefunc)
    p.start()
    print p.name
```

Comment: okay, now searching for current_process in the docs I find the method at http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#miscellaneous
guess, I need to RTFM with a little more patience and concentration :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing `target` argument, override the `run` method.  From there, you can invoke `someFunc` and pass the process object to it.

The name is not an OS level concept.  It is Python level and it is not automatic that the process you execute in even has a `Process` object anywhere.